# Convolution of probabilities

Tags: probability, convolution

It is a well known fact that for a random variable $Z=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$ where $Y_i$ are independently distributed then the probability density function of $Z$ is the convolution of the density functions of the random variables $Y_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. In other words if $f_Z$ stands for the density function of $Z$ then $$f_Z=f_{Y_1}\ast f_{Y_2}\ast...\ast f_{Y_n}$$
where $\ast$ stands for the convolution operation. However is the converse true? If we have $f_Z=f_{Y_1}\ast f_{Y_2}\ast...\ast f_{Y_n}$ does it follow that $Z=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$ where $Y_i$ are independently distributed. This might be an elementary fact but I can not see an immediate way to prove or disprove this. Any suggestion would be more than welcome.

Comment: If the $f_{Y_i}$ are density functions and $f_Z=f_{Y_1}\ast f_{Y_2}\ast\cdots\ast f_{Y_n}$ , then there are independent random variables $Y_i$ such that the distribution of $Z$ is the same as the  distribution of $Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$, but this is not quite what you are asking.

Comment: So when $f_{Y_i}$ are restricted only to density functions then the statement becomes biconditional. Did I get this right?

Comment: There is a key difference between proving the existence of $Y_i$ such that $Z=Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$ and the existence of $Y_i$ such that $Z$ has the same distribution as $Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a counterexample to what you think may be true.

Let $U_1, U_2$ be iid $N(\mu=9, \sigma^2 = 9).$

Let $V_1, V_2, V_3$ be iid $N(6, 6).$

Let $W_1, W_2, \dots, W_9$ be iid $N(2, 2).$

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{18}$ be iid $N(1, 1).$

Then $\sum_{i=1}^2 U_i,\; \sum_{i=1}^3 V_i,\; \sum_{i=1}^9 W_i,\;$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{18} X_i$ are all distributed $N(18, 18).$

So if you know that $Z \sim N(18, 18),$ then there is no
unique way to express it is a sum of iid random variables.

As a practical matter, because of the Central Limit Theorem,
if you knew that a normal random variable is the sum of $n = 1000$
iid random variables, you wouldn't be able to guess
whether the 1000 'pieces' were distributed normal, uniform, Poisson, or according 
any of a number of other distributions.

Your question is not exactly clear to me. If you had something
else in mind, please leave a Comment and I (or someone else)
will likely be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact I am not looking for the uniqueness of expressing $Z$ as a sum of independent distributions (not necessarily identical distributions). What I am interested in is: Given a random variable $Z$ with a certain pdf which is also expressible as the convolution of certain finite number of other pdf-s, in general does it follow that $Z$ is the sum of respective random variables of the convoluted pdf-s? Also I am not stating that it should absolutely be true, on the contrary I just can not find a direct way of proving or disproving it.

Comment: If I understand you, yes. Convolution of densities means that RVs associated with those densities sum to RV having dist'n of convolution. It's trying to "de-convolve" the sum into unspecified 'pieces' that is not unique. Seems several of us thought you were asking about de-convolution. Do you have the answer you are looking for?

Comment: I do not have one yet Bruce.

Comment: Between the Comment of @Henry and my Answer, it seems to me the issue as I understood it is handled. Maybe you can take a careful look at Q, C & A, then try to help us focus on what is not yet answered. Are you having trouble understanding (a) how the convolution formula relates to sums of RVs, (b) how to find the (unique) convolution of several RVs, (c) given a single RV how to express it as a convolution of multiple RVs (not unique), or (d) something else entirely?

Comment: It is more related to (c). If you have a single random variable with a pdf that can be expressed as a convolution of certain number of other pdf-s. De-convolving the expression, do we obtain that this single random variable is a sum of the respective random variables of the other pdf-s? Should these other RV-s be independent? Second what if the original pdf is a convolution of certain functions not necessarily pdf-s, what can we say applying the same process?

Comment: On (c), NO. If you convolve U and V to get X, then just looking at X, you cannot necessarily retrieve U and V. That's the msg of my Answer. Your other questions seem to be new issues. If U and V are not indep, then U+V has a dist'n, but I wouldn't call that a convolution. Would your convolution formula give the right answer? And there is no guarantee that a RV can be de-convolved meaningfully. What two RVs sum to Bernoulli(1/2)? We are about to get busted for doing a chat via Comments, so I'll end with those obs/quest. Maybe someone else will find something interesting or useful to say.